# How to set opacity/ transparancy on view/ List view row

Tags: android, listview, transparency, opacity

In my code i have state for each row of content so in list view if row has state as read, i need to display it with opacity/ transparency but for the view there is no direct method to set alpha.

```
if(termDetails.getInt("isRead") > 0) {
    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.2f);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    rowView.setAnimation(animation);
} else {
    AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 1);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    rowView.setAnimation(animation);
}
```

Above code works but it is unstable as u scroll through list it looses the consistency.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this in your xml file where the part you want transparent will be...

```
android:background="#00000000"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Comment: I think what you mean is something like "#66000000" - the first 2 numbers are the opacity.

Comment: this is just setting the background color and hint for it. the question is how to set the listview row/item transparent - NOT how to set the items background transparent, but the entire item. the animation method works, but when scrolling there's anomalies and it would be nice to know why.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the colors are mentioned as #AARRGGBB where

A - Alpha
R - Red,
G - Green,
B - Blue

and each component varies between 00 - FF. In the case of Alpha, 00 is transparent while FF is 100% opacity.

Set the background of the item that you want to be transparent as #00RRGGBB